# Restart Windows Jenkins slave in the beginning of a job or before a job

Tags: jenkins, loadrunner

**Problem:** 
My job failed on Delete.

> [14:12:28] [WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace... [14:12:37]
>   ERROR: [WS-CLEANUP] Cannot delete workspace: remote file operation
>   failed: c:\jenkins\workspace\v3000.0.0-CI-3-QA-LoadRunner_2012_18 at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel@387682a8:JNLP4-connect connection from
>   192.168.11.149/192.168.11.149:34302: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete
>   'c:\jenkins\workspace\v3000.0.0-CI-3-QA-LoadRunner_2012_18.git\objects\pack\pack-edfa06b8e1b0e8e57d244e1d6085bd6fedeb8392.pack'.
>   Tried 3 times (of a maximum of 3) waiting 0.1 sec between attempts.
>   [14:12:37] ERROR: Cannot delete workspace: remote file operation
>   failed: c:\jenkins\workspace\v3000.0.0-CI-3-QA-LoadRunner_2012_18 at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel@387682a8:JNLP4-connect connection from
>   192.168.11.149/192.168.11.149:34302: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete
>   'c:\jenkins\workspace\v3000.0.0-CI-3-QA-LoadRunner_2012_18.git\objects\pack\pack-edfa06b8e1b0e8e57d244e1d6085bd6fedeb8392.pack'.
>   Tried 3 times (of a maximum of 3) waiting 0.1 sec between attempts.
>   [14:12:37] Recording test results [14:12:37] ERROR: Step ‘Publish
>   Micro Focus tests result’ failed: Test reports were found but none of
>   them are new. Did leafNodes run?

**Solution:**
Manually Log in to Slave machine and restart Jenkins Slave agent that apparently lock a file there...
Then I can rebuild....

**Required Solution:**
I thought on creating ability automatically to restart Jenkins Slave before each run. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should solve the actual issue of figuring out why the delete fails and not try a workaround of restarting the slave

Comment: I do not have solution to the delete option currently just restart slave agent.

Comment: Then I would remove the loadrunner and microfocus tags as this is not a solution our plugin can provide

Comment: @Buzzy - We still did not upgrade to 5.9 (Dependency staff )... It might be solved in 5.9.

Comment: It was solved via upgrade to HP Jenkins add-in to 5.9

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved via upgrade to: Microfocus Application Automation Tools v5.9